# PIVOT query not giving me correct output in OEM 13C

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a PIVOT query to get system and sysaux tablespace growth for the last 15 days. The query not giving me a correct output . It shows number with E. My enterprise manager verison in 13C and repository db version is 12.1.0.2. I would appreciate if someone can help me out. May be i making mistakes while converting to GB. Please help.

```
with pivot_data AS (
         select target_name, key_value, to_char(rollup_timestamp,'mm/dd/yy')as DT, average
         from sysman.mgmt$metric_daily
         where target_TYPE in ('rac_database') AND KEY_VALUE in ('SYSTEM','SYSAUX') AND TARGET_NAME IN ('DBKUH','ETPUZ','ZLDFK')
and column_label = 'Tablespace Used Space (MB)'
         and trunc(rollup_timestamp) >= trunc(sysdate)-15)
    select * from pivot_data
    pivot
         ( sum(average/1024/1024/1024)
           for TARGET_NAME 
          in ( 'DBKUH' AS ETPUZ,'ETPUZ' AS ETPUZ,'ZLDFK' AS ZLDFK )
         )
  order by DT
/
```

Comment: Please learn how to use the formatting tools - it's really trivial. Formatting code in particular.

Comment: I am sorry buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the average over a column labeled `'Tablespace Used Space(MB)'`. I will venture to guess it's a size in MB, so to convert to GB you should only divide by 1024 once.

Other things I noticed:

- in PIVOT, did you mean `'DBKUH' as ETPUZ` or is that a typo?
- also in PIVOT, you are adding 15 daily averages... did you mean to
  average them?
- `trunc(timestamp) >= trunc(sysdate)-15` is equivalent
  to `timestamp >= ...` and the latter will allow you to use an index
  on `timestamp` while the former will not.

Comment: Yes these are not typo.

Comment: @user3297431 - I don't understand, are you saying `'DBKUH as ETPUZ` is not a typo? You will get two columns both with the name `ETPUZ` in the output to PIVOT?

Comment: I do apology. Yes it was a typo.